# Python program computing some statistics on Scottish geographic areas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics, pandas

This simple script computes some basic descriptive statistics, like mean, standard deviation, kurtosis, etc. on data column imported from a CSV file with use of `pandas`. In addition, the script accepts argument `--exclude_zeros` and computes the desired statistics excluding zeros. The script delivers the desired results. However, as I come from R background, I would be happy receive feedback on a proper / *pythonic* way of generating the desired results.

**Data**

The data pertains to geographic area sizes of neighbourhood geographies for Scotland and is publicly available. This and other similar data sets can be sourced from [Scottish Government open data portal](https://statistics.gov.scot/home).

```
#!/Users/me/path/path/path/bin/python
"""DZ Area check
The script sources uses previously used area size file and produces
some descriptive statistics. The script additionally computes statistics
excluding zeros.
"""

# Modules
# Refresh requirements creation:
# $ pipreqs --force ~/where/this/stuff/sits/
import os
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import numpy as np


# Main function running the program
def main(csv_data, exclude):
    """Computer the desired area statisics"""
    data = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=csv_data,
        skiprows=7,
        encoding='utf-8',
        header=None,
        names=['datazone', 'usual_residenrs', 'area_hectares'])
    print('\nSourced table:\r')
    print(tabulate(data.head(), headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
    # Replace zero if required
    if exclude:
        data = data.replace(0, np.NaN)
    # Compute statistics
    area_mean = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].mean()
    area_max = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].max()
    area_min = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].min()
    area_total = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].sum()
    obs_count = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].count()
    obs_dist = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].nunique(
    )  # Count distinct observations
    area_variance = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].var()
    area_median = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].median()
    area_std = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].std()
    area_skw = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].skew()
    area_kurt = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].kurtosis()
    # Create results object
    results = {
        'Statistic': [
            'Average', 'Max', 'Min', 'Total', 'Count', 'Count (distinct)',
            'Variance', 'Median', 'SD', 'Skewness', 'Kurtosis'
        ],
        'Value': [
            area_mean, area_max, area_min, area_total, obs_count, obs_dist,
            area_variance, area_median, area_std, area_skw, area_kurt
        ]
    }
    # Show results object
    print('\nArea statistics:\r')
    print(
        tabulate(
            results,
            headers='keys',
            tablefmt='psql',
            numalign='left',
            floatfmt='.2f'))
    return (results)


# Import arguments. Solves running program as a module and as a standalone
# file.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Calculate basic geography statistics.',
        epilog='Data Zone Area Statistics\rKonrad')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i',
        '--infile',
        nargs=1,
        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
        help='Path to data file with geography statistics.',
        default=os.path.join('/Users', 'me', 'folder', 'data', 'folder',
                             'import_folder', 'stuff.csv'))
    parser.add_argument(
        '--exclude-zeros',
        dest='exclude_zeros',
        action='store_true',
        default=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Call main function and computse stats
    main(csv_data=args.infile, exclude=args.exclude_zeros)
```

## Results

```
Sourced table:
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|    | datazone   |   usual_residenrs |   area_hectares |
|----+------------+-------------------+-----------------|
|  0 | S01000001  |               872 |          438.88 |
|  1 | S01000002  |               678 |           30.77 |
|  2 | S01000003  |               788 |           13.36 |
|  3 | S01000004  |               612 |           20.08 |
|  4 | S01000005  |               643 |           27.02 |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+

Area statistics:
+------------------+-------------+
| Statistic        | Value       |
|------------------+-------------|
| Average          | 1198.11     |
| Max              | 116251.04   |
| Min              | 0.00        |
| Total            | 7793711.31  |
| Count            | 6505.00     |
| Count (distinct) | 4200.00     |
| Variance         | 35231279.23 |
| Median           | 22.00       |
| SD               | 5935.59     |
| Skewness         | 9.77        |
| Kurtosis         | 121.59      |
+------------------+-------------+
```

### Results (excluding zeros)

```
Sourced table:
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|    | datazone   |   usual_residenrs |   area_hectares |
|----+------------+-------------------+-----------------|
|  0 | S01000001  |               872 |          438.88 |
|  1 | S01000002  |               678 |           30.77 |
|  2 | S01000003  |               788 |           13.36 |
|  3 | S01000004  |               612 |           20.08 |
|  4 | S01000005  |               643 |           27.02 |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+

Area statistics:
+------------------+-------------+
| Statistic        | Value       |
|------------------+-------------|
| Average          | 1199.03     |
| Max              | 116251.04   |
| Min              | 1.24        |
| Total            | 7793711.31  |
| Count            | 6500.00     |
| Count (distinct) | 4199.00     |
| Variance         | 35257279.16 |
| Median           | 22.01       |
| SD               | 5937.78     |
| Skewness         | 9.77        |
| Kurtosis         | 121.49      |
+------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we wanted to add a new statistic, what would we have to do? Well, we'd need to make three changes:

1. Compute the statistic and put its value in a new variable:

   ```
   new_statistic = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"].new_statistic()
   ```
2. Add the name of the new statistic to `results['Statistic']`.
3. Add the new variable to `results['Value']`.

But when we do *1* and *3,* there's a risk that we might put the name and value in different positions in the lists, causing the tabulated output to be wrong.

To avoid this risk, we'd like to have a single place to put the information about the new statistic. There are two things to know about a statistic: its name, and which function to call to compute it. So I would make a global table of statistics, like this:

```
# List of statistics to compute, as pairs (statistic name, method name).
STATISTICS = [
    ('Average',          'mean'),
    ('Max',              'max'),
    ('Min',              'min'),
    ('Total',            'sum'),
    ('Count',            'count'),
    ('Count (distinct)', 'nunique'),
    ('Variance',         'var'),
    ('Median',           'median'),
    ('SD',               'std'),
    ('Skewness',         'skew'),
    ('Kurtosis',         'kurtosis'),
]
```

And then it's easy to build the `results` dictionary by iterating over the global table and using [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
from operator import methodcaller
column = data.loc[:, "area_hectares"]
results = {
    'Statistic': [name for name, _ in STATISTICS],
    'Value': [methodcaller(method)(column) for _, method in STATISTICS],
}
```

Now if we need to add a new statistic, we only need to make one change (adding a line to the `STATISTICS` list), and there's no risk of putting the name and value in different positions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I like your approach to computing additional statistics. As a matter of fact, this is what I would be looking to do in R using `match.fun` or `get` as in `match.fun("mean")` to compute mean.